# Any way to display xen guest OS on physical host monitor?

Tags: virtual-machine, xen

Using Xen virtualization, is there a way to make one of the guests residing on the Xen VM Server, to point it's gui to the local physical monitor?  Normally I just VNC in from a different machine, but was wondering if there was a way to use just *ONE* machine and still have the gui interface to the vm guest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
I share my server with my wife. Its running Win8 as Home Server and points to my Hadeon as GPU.

[image]

Comment: Could you express on how you set this up? I'm currently trying with xenserver with an onboard gpu and a separate nvidia gpu for passthrough. I would like to use the VM on the exact same host as xenserver is run on. The xenserver console should be displayed on the vga output of the internal gpu and the vm should be displayed on the hdmi of the nvidia gpu. Is this really possible? I could not find any configuration switches in the UI.. (xenserver console and XenCenter)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible with citrix xenserver, newer versions of citrix xenserver have a gui, if you want to use the screen mouse and keyboard whilst running VM's, you either need to use the opensource version of xen from a linux distribution where a full version of linux is available to run the remote client software to connect to one of your vm's.

Personally I would not recommend this as citrix xen server is specifically cut down to provide a "near bare metal experience" for hosted virtual machines, if this is for home use or testing purposes then I would suggest using a desktop virtualization technology instead such as virtual box or similar offerings from vmware workstation or microsoft virtual pc depending on what it is that you want to achieve.